# Why does loading the Rserve() package result in "'CreateProcess' failed to run" error?

Tags: r, tableau-api, rserve

I want to use R with Tableau, and have been following the instructions to connect them found here:
https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/how-integrate-r-and-tableau

I am able to install the Rserve package just fine, but keep running into this "'CreateProcess' failed to run" error whenever I try to load Rserve() in my RGui console. Is the solution related to setting a correct directory/workspace? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Links to relevant information can be useful for reference, but when they require registration or authentication, you're a little less likely to get people who either (1) have already registered for it and can see that, or (2) are willing to register just for the sake of helping you here. Can you include enough context from that link (without making the question too big)?

Comment: Sorry about that! The link just instructs a user to 1. Download R 2. Install the Rserve package and load the package with the commands "install.packages("Rserve"); library("Rserve"); Rserve()". The last command is where I am getting an 'CreateProcess' failed to run error. I am wondering how to address that.